# Fishing with unclean bait

Tags: fish

I cannot seem to find a straight answer if it is permissible to catch fish with non-kosher bait (e.g., squid, mussels and other non-kosher fish)?.

Does Leviticus 11 speak against eating only or would it include touching non-kosher fish as bait?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Brumar and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

One may use non-kosher bait to fish ,the prohibition is eating non-kosher,and doing business with non-kosher items(Yoreh Deah 117:1). However,it should be noted that to store edible  non-kosher for a lengthy period of time in one's homes may be problematic since one may come to eat it by mistake.

Rav Aviner answers simply that it is permitted.

English translation is mine:

ש: האם אפשר לדוג דג עם פתיון לא כשר

Q: Is it possible(permissible)to fish with non-kosher bait?

ת: כן (עי' שו"ת שאילת שלמה ד קעד).

A: Yes, (see Shu"t Sheilat Shlomo 4:174)

Comment: For beginners -- it's an excellent question as it's not always clear from a simple reading of Leviticus which non-kosher foods simply can't be eaten, and which can't be used at all. The Talmud clarifies that a non-kosher animal can be used by not eaten, whereas something like meat-cooked-in-milk can't even be sold or burned for fuel. Therefore, the Talmud says if I'm a kosher fisherman with occasional non-kosher bycatch, I can sell those to non-Jews. The Talmud prohibits, however, making a day job out of selling "unclean" foods. It seems bait isn't considered selling the stuff for a living.

Comment: The selling aspect is a side note ,but simply using non-kosher bait is permissible.  Also the sugya of YD 117 is not black and white ,since some items can be sold